# Login a Website and Web Scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out ways to web scraping a real estate website https://www.brickz.my/ for my research project. I have been trying between selenium and beautiful soup and decide to choose beautiful soup was the best way for me since the structure of url for each real estate allow my code to navigate the website easily and faster

I am trying to build a database transaction for each real estate'. Without login, only 10 latest transactions will be displayed for a particular property. By login, I can access to the whole transaction for a particular type of property. here is the example

[without login, i can only access 10 transaction for each property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37P3.jpg)

[After login, i can access to more than 10 transaction plus previously obscure property address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glbjv.jpg)

i try to login using request in python, yet it keep bringing me to the page without login and end up, i just manage to scrap the 10 latest transaction instead of whole transaction. here is the example of my login code in python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.brickz.my/login/", auth=
('email', 'password'))

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G928X Build/LMY47X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#I put one of the property url to be scrapped inside response
response = get("https://www.brickz.my/transactions/residential/kuala- 
           lumpur/titiwangsa/titiwangsa-sentral-condo/non-landed/?range=2012+Oct-", 
           headers = headers)
```

Here is what I used to scrape the table

```
  table = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

  names = []   
  for tr in table_rows:
      td = tr.find_all('td')
      row = [i.text for i in td]
      names.append(row)
```

How am I able to successfully login and get access to the whole transaction? I heard about Mechanize library but it is not available for python 3.

I am sorry if my question is not clear, this is my first time posting, and i just learn to use python only a couple of months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. What do you see when you print it (changing `email` and `password`)? Doesn't it print `Logout`as result?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.brickz.my/login/"

payload = {
'email': 'your_email',
'pw': 'your_password',
'submit': 'Submit'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    s.post(URL,data=payload)
    res = s.get("https://www.brickz.my/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for items in soup.select("select#menu_select .nav2"):
        data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select("option")[-1:]]
        print(data)
```

Comment: Hi @SIM, i did what you old, and print Logout as result. may i know what can i do to overcome this?

Comment: What do you wanna overcome, actually? I tried to mean that you can only see `Logout` option when you are already logged in.

Comment: im sorry for my ignorant, i thought that Logout mean im still not log in. Thanks for the clarification, i managed to to scrap the table now after running your code to login. Thankl you so much!!!!!:):)

Answer (score 1):

A simple HTTP trace will show that a POST is made to `https://www.brickz.my/login/` with `email` and `pw` as form parameters.

Which translates into this requests command:

```
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.post('https://www.brickz.my/login/', data={'email': '<youremail>', 'pw': '<yourpassword'})
if resp.ok:
    print("You should now be logged in")

# then use session to request the site, like 
# resp = session.get("https://www.brickz.my/whatever")
```

WARNING: Untested since I don't have an account there.

Comment: Hi @Guillaume. Thank you for the fast feedback. I tried your advice and put the newly declared resp inside the beautifulSoup for the table, yet i still faced the same problem. I did some experimentation by inserting fake email and fake password in the session.get. I still got "You should now be logged in". Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: That completely depends on the website. Additionnal the website can have some kind protection features against bots, which block non-browser to login and use the site properly.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I got the solution for my problem. Anyway, appreciate your kind effort in assisting me :)