# Webscrape A Website After Logging Into It Using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I would like to webscrape 'alertasubastas.com' after logging into it.

I have tried something like this:

```
payload = {'action': 'login', 'email': 'mail@gmail.com', 'password':'drowssap'}

c = requests.session()
c.post('https://alertasubastas.com/login', data=payload)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login a Website and Web Scapping using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560494/login-a-website-and-web-scapping-using-python)

Comment: The form is submitted via GET request (use `params` for your data), but note that there is one more hidden `csrf_token` field.